# Regex in innerHTML to check for 2 numbers and one letter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an if statement in my Chrome extension that checks a page for listings to see if any match something in particular, such as:

```
if(matches[i].innerHTML.includes("12B"){
```

and that works fine. All said and done, the full return of `matches[i].innerHTML` will always be something like:

"12B Example"

So I'm primary interested in the initial 2 numbers, then a specific letter. So I want to add an additional check in the if statement to see if it matches any 2 numbers, then followed by the letter B specifically. Then after the B, I don't care what is there, I want it to be considered a match.

I tried the following:

```
if(matches[i].innerHTML.includes(/^[0-9]{2}[B]{1}/){
```

and that doesn't seem to be working. Is that sort of expression valid in setting?

I also tried: `([0-9]{2}[B]{1})` and similar. I looked here and in the documentation but wasn't able to find anything that gets me any further.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Replace `includes` with `match`. Also replace `^` with `\b` to match anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will evaluate that there is 2 numbers and the B letter in capital at the beginning of the string, after that it will check if there's any other values or if it's empty.

```
if(matches[i].innerHTML.match(/^[0-9]{2}B.*$/)
```

Examples:

- 12B
- 01B46598
- 99B46zAw%$